# How to open the downloaded file in new browser window c#

Tags: javascript, c#, multifile-uploader, server.mappath

i am trying to open the downloaded file from database in a new browser window..

here is code that i tried..

```
result = objBL.GetLetter(LetterID, refNo, attachmentType);
            if (result != null && result.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow dr = result.Rows[0];
                string fileName = dr["FileName"].ToString();
                Response.ContentType = ContentType;
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(fileName));
                Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/Attachments/" + fileName));
                Response.End();
            }
```

is there any syntax to open in jquery?

Comment: The `Content-Disposition` key you are adding is a suggestion to download the file. Remove the header and open the link in a blank tab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open PDF file in a new tab or window instead of downloading it (using asp.net)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294057/how-to-open-pdf-file-in-a-new-tab-or-window-instead-of-downloading-it-using-asp)

Comment: @Liam i couldn't found my answer in that link...

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided isn't jQuery, it's C#. This question actually has nothing to do with jQuery, so please be mindful not to add irrelevant tags to your question next time :).

To open a (downloaded) file in the browser, set the `Content-Disposition` header for your `Response` object to `inline`. Currently, you are setting it to `attachment` which forces it to be downloaded as a file instead of being displayed in the browser.

Example:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(fileName));
```

Comment: I think the jquery tag is because the Op would accept a jquery solution, that said why jquery and not javascript..

Comment: The code that he posted which he tried was C#, which is why I assumed he wanted a C# solution.

Comment: The code you posted leads me to believe this is a result from a `Controller` action. You don't have access to jQuery there.