# How to open a pdf file in the web browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I want to **display a pdf**. My current code displayit using a pdf reader. But I want to open it in a **seperate tab of the browser**. How can i do it? I have a link button inside the web page. I have set this in onClick method. How to open it using back end code? (not using a link in aspx)

Here is my code

```
string name = ddlAppealList.SelectedValue.ToString();
int refNo = Convert.ToInt32(name);
string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/filesPDF/" + refNo + ".pdf");
WebClient User = new WebClient();
Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(FilePath);
if (FileBuffer != null)
{
     Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
     Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
     Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Open the target in new window beforehand, for example `<a href="viewpdf.aspx" target="_blank">View PDF</a>`. Gotten from [How to open PDF file in a new tab or window instead of downloading it (using asp.net)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294057/how-to-open-pdf-file-in-a-new-tab-or-window-instead-of-downloading-it-using-asp)

Comment: isn't this behavior also tied to the brwoser configuration and/or availability of a inline pdf viewer ?

Answer (score 1):

Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
    Response.TransmitFile(PDFfilepath);

For opening the PDF file in a new tab or windows you can use following html code:

```
<a href="view.aspx" target="_blank">View</a>
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: @Ashouri, this code doesn't work as i expected. It opens a tab. But again close it automatically and as usal it asks to open the pdf file. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar situation a few weeks ago. This piece of code, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894771/1672375), helped me solve the issue:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition { Inline = true, FileName = "pdfname.pdf" }.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to open a pdf in a C# web application with `ActionResult`. You can also store the pdf as a byte[] in the database to make this code simpler.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ViewPdf()
{    
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    FileStream stream = new FileStream("mypdf.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    stream.CopyTo(ms);

    return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
}
```