# MVC.Net Open a file in a new window instead of downloading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, download

My requirement is to open a file in a new window/tab upon clicking the download link. The file is always downloaded despite setting the content disposition to 'inline' as suggested in the below post.

[How to open PDF file in a new tab or window instead of downloading it (using asp.net)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294057/how-to-open-pdf-file-in-a-new-tab-or-window-instead-of-downloading-it-using-asp)

My HTTP response is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
content-disposition: inline;filename=FileName.pdf
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 141954
```

My Controller Action is as below -

```
public async Task<FileContentResult> Index(string fileName)
    {
        byte[] document = await getFileContent("SomePathForTheFile");
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + document.FileName);
        return File(document, "application/octet-stream");
    }
```

Suggestions to make the file open automatically in a new tab/window instead of just being downloaded would be of great help! Thanks!

Comment: Set your Content-Type to application/pdf

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.

2 things have to be done for the file to open in a new window -

1.content-disposition must be set to inline

2.the content type should be set to the type corresponding to the file being downloaded -

application/pdf - for pdf files

application/xml  - for xml files

application/vnd.ms-excel - for xls files and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index",null,new { @target="_blank" })
```

Since we are returning to the view mode, there is no need to mention about header response

```
public async Task<FileContentResult> Index(string fileName)
    {
        byte[] document = await getFileContent("SomePathForTheFile");
        return File(document, "application/octet-stream");
    }
```

Comment: Hi, only upon setting the content type to 'application/pdf' instead of 'application/octet-stream', i got it working. Thanks for your suggestion.