# pdf files automatically downloaded in website created using C1 CMS

Tags: c#

I am using C1 CMS 6.0. I noticed that when I am giving a pdf file which is uploaded in  media  section as a link to a some text and when I click the text while using the web page it is getting downloaded.Instead I want it to open in a new browser tab.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294057/how-to-open-pdf-file-in-a-new-tab-or-window-instead-of-downloading-it-using-asp

Comment: Agree with @SouvikGhosh, check for content-type first. Also it depends on the client browser (in particular, installed plugins) how the file will be handled.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.But i got a perfect solution from C1 CMS team.
Just add ?download=false at the end of the pdf link

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this as an answer for the people to find the answer easily.

Yes You just have to add "?download=false" at the end of the pdf link.

Thanks, Hope this helps.